# Show that $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ are iid Bernoulli

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Problem statement: Suppose $X_1, X_2, \dots$ are iid Bernoulli random variables. Let $f_0$ be a constant, either $0$ or $1$. Let, for each $k \in \mathbb N$, $f_k = \{0,1\}^k \to \{0,1\}$ be a function.
$$Y_n := \sum_{k=1}^nf_{k-1}(X_1, \dots, X_{k-1})X_k, ~~~~ n \in N$$
Show that $Y_1, Y_2, \dots$ are iid Bernoulli random variables.

This question doesn't make sense to me. Consider $Y_1$. By definition, $Y_1 = f_0X_1$. If $f_0=0$, then $Y_1$ is identically $0$, not Bernoulli. So we fail on the first simple example. I braved on, assuming that the question was suppose to say that $f_0 = 1$, and continued to try to prove the result by induction.

The inductive step becomes

\begin{align}
\mathbb P(Y_n = 0) & = \mathbb P(\sum_{k=1}^nf_{k-1}(X_1, \dots, X_k-1)X_k = 0) \\[10pt]
& = \mathbb P \left( \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f_{k-1}(X_1, \dots, X_k-1)X_k + f_{n-1}(X_1, \dots , X_{n-1})X_n = 0\right) \\[10pt]
& = \mathbb P(Y_{n-1} + f_{n-1}(X_1, \dots , X_{n-1})X_n = 0)
\end{align}

But if $Y_{n-1}$ is Bernoulli, then the only way for this probability to be $1/2$ is if $f_{n-1}$ is identically zero. So the sequence is Bernoulli iff $f_0 = 1$ and $f_k = 0$, $k \geq 1$.

This does not feel like a good answer to the question, which I interpret to be about showing that the sequence is Bernoulli for any function. Is the question weird, or did I go wrong somewhere?

Comment: An identically $0$ random variable is Bernoulli with parameter $0$

Comment: Yes, thank you @ThomasAndrews

Comment: If the $f_k$ are identically $1$, $Y_n$ is definitely not Bernoulli.

Comment: @eepperly16 Yes, but then I need all the $f_k$ to be identically zero for the $Y_i$ to be iid, so I still don't like it.

Comment: @JackM Exactly. SO many issues with this question.